# How to remove repetitive parameters in class methods?

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I've got a class implementing an interface, with some 15 methods. The methods all need a `string SectorId` that is passed onward to another service, which make the class looks like this:

```
public class A: IA {
 public string A1(string sectorId, ....) => _otherService.B1(sectorId, ....);
 public string A2(string sectorId, ....) => _otherService.B2(sectorId, ....);
 public string A3(string sectorId, ....) => _otherService.B2(sectorId, ....);
 public string A4(string sectorId, ....) => _otherService.B2(sectorId, ....);
 ...
}
```

Is it possible to get rid of the repetitive `string sectorId` while still achieving the same objective? This class handles webAPI calls and is dependency injected to the controller which calls it.

I thought of having the sectorId as a constructor initialized parameter, but that would mean either not using the class as a DI singleton and, instead, scoping it to the request or not using DI altogether and just initializing it on every request. Is there a better way to handle this?

Comment: _"Is there a better way to handle this"_ - no, you either provide the data as method parameter or create an instance which will hold the data (ideally in read-only mode).

Answer (score 1):

You can move `sectorId` to a constructor param.

Then, instead of injecting `IA` as a dependency, you can inject an `IAFactory` with a `createIA(sectorId: string)` method.